# Add a Financial Type to Existing Custom Field Profile

Tags: custom-fields, contributions

Years ago, when we started using CiviCRM, I added a custom field to the New Contribution dialog on the backend of Civi (we're using it on WordPress, if that makes any difference). I'm not asking about public contribution pages.

So the custom field is in a custom data set, and appears on the New Contribution page perfectly. The custom field appears when a financial type of Donation, Member Dues, Campaign Contribution, and In-Kind is selected.

Now I've added a new financial type, and want the custom field to appear with the new financial type. I'll never get back the hour I just spent tearing apart the administration pages, looking for where I can do that, frustrated that I didn't find anywhere to edit the types.

And in Googling around, I kept seeing advice to be very careful to select financial types carefully, so that I think I finally understand that the financial types associated with a custom field are not updateable.

Is that really the case? And if so, really? I can understand needing to be careful, but stuff changes in seven years.

If that's not the case, how do I do add the new financial type to the list where the custom field appears?

Thanks!
Don

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> Customize data and screens >> Custom Fields.

Look for the custom set you want to set the new financial type.

Click on More >> Settings

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I missed that.